# Log4j to write to one file per instance

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j

I'm writing an application that will on a tomcat server. The application is instantiated multiple times for each client we serve.

I'm introducing Log4j to the application. A client file will be created and log outputs will be written to it.

The problem Im facing is that every time a new instance is created, log outputs from other clients are written to the new client log file.

Within the app, I instantiate the logger for each log like this:

```
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(name_of_class.class);
```

How can I make sure that previous instances of the application will only log to its own file and not spill over to other clients?

Comment: The client is a browser. You instanticate the Application once for a browser??

Comment: Sorry, should have been clearer. The client is an actual client that is using the application. I.e, company1, company2 etc

Comment: There is just one `Log` file and your application is writing to it. There is no such solution to have a separate log file for each client (although you can implement it but that is not the purpose of log files)

Comment: The purpose of having a log file for each client is to allow us to easily see log outputs for each instance of the application clearly and to only see outputs for that instance and no other. For one instance it works fine, for more than one, I get crossover.

Comment: Would Apaches Separate logging functionality help with this?

Comment: I've also tried setting the additivity of the logger to false but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I Managed to solve it.

The problem lied in naming the logger after class it resided in. What I did was move the logger declaration to a method that is called by the other classes.

When the method is called, it instantiates a logger named after the client i.e.

Logger.getLogger("ClientName");

This way the outputs are always written to the client file only, even if the classes are instantiated the client logger is called.

Thanks for helping me through the thought process.